# Could not determine dialect for SQlite, following Flask tutorial

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask

I am following [this tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) which is brilliant to learn Flask.

I typed in all the code to create a database using SQLAlchemy-Migrate , but when I run `db_create.py`, I get an error saying

```
'Could not determine dialect for SQLite'
```

Comment: What is the *exact* exception you see? Don't type it, copy and paste it. The error message is certainly incomplete as posted, as there are quotes in that message.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` connection string; the driver value is case sensitive, you cannot capitalize `SQLite` in it, it *has* to be all lowercase:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
```

The exception you see is thrown by SQLAlchemy trying to use the first part of the connection string to find the right database dialect, and it won't find `SQLite`, but will work for `sqlite`.